# How to align divs on top? html-css

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this slider which is working with Tiny slider js. Each slide has a header (pink div) and the content inside another div (green div). How can I align the green divs to the top when one of the headers has more text than the others?

I think the pink divs should grow but up and not down so that the green divs are top aligned. Is there any way to do that?

Please help!!!

```js
    const tabsSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.js-slider');
    tabsSlider.forEach(slider => {

        const tnsSlider = tns({
            container: slider,
            mouseDrag: true,
            nav: false,
            controls: false,
            items: 2,
            loop: false,
            slideBy: 2,
            mode: "carousel",
            swipeAngle: false,
            edgePadding: 30,
            speed: 400,
        });
    });
```

```css
.slider-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.slide-heading {
  background-color: pink;
}

.slide-heading p,
.slide-heading h4{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.slide-content {
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.4/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrapper js-slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slide-box">
            <div class="slide-heading">
                <h4 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>                    
                <p  class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores!</p>
            </div><!--/.slide-heading-->
            <div class="slide-content">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus, aperiam quasi voluptates assumenda neque fugiat. Enim ipsa quos facere, similique, iste placeat aperiam veniam, numquam qui neque illum odio!</p>
                </div><!--/.description-->
            </div><!--/.slide-content-->
        </div><!--/.slide-box-->
    </div><!--/.slide-->
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slide-box">
            <div class="slide-heading">
                <h4 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>                    
                <p  class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores!</p>
            </div><!--/.slide-heading-->
            <div class="slide-content">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus, aperiam quasi voluptates assumenda neque fugiat. Enim ipsa quos facere, similique, iste placeat aperiam veniam, numquam qui neque illum odio!</p>
                </div><!--/.description-->
            </div><!--/.slide-content-->
        </div><!--/.slide-box-->
    </div><!--/.slide-->
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slide-box">
            <div class="slide-heading">
                <h4 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>                    
                <p  class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores!</p>
            </div><!--/.slide-heading-->
            <div class="slide-content">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus, aperiam quasi voluptates assumenda neque fugiat. Enim ipsa quos facere, similique, iste placeat aperiam veniam, numquam qui neque illum odio!</p>
                </div><!--/.description-->
            </div><!--/.slide-content-->
        </div><!--/.slide-box-->
    </div><!--/.slide-->
</div><!--/.slider-wrapper-->
```

Comment: You could get the layout you want with Flexbox or Grid, but you'd need to reduce the number of inner containers so that those boxes were all direct children. I would use Grid to arrange them in columns and rows, and just make the pink and green content paragraphs that are direct children of the container.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the layout you want, you need to use a grid. Tinyslider uses flexboxes for layout, so it isn’t suitable.

```css
.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;    /* we want a grid with two rows of automatic height */
  grid-auto-flow: column;           /* fill the first column, then add columns as required */
  grid-auto-columns: 200px;         /* make each column 200px wide */
  gap: 2px 1em;                     
}

.d1>* {                             /* child elements are slides */
  display: contents;
}

.d1>*>* {                           /* grandchild elements are either headings or contents*/
  padding: 10px;
}

.d1>*>*:first-child {               /* first grandchild in each slide is a heading */
  background-color: pink;
  align-self: end;                  /* align the bottoms of the pink boxes */
}

.d1>*>*:last-child {                /* last grandchild in each slide is contents */
  background-color: greenyellow;
  align-self: start;                /* align the tops of the green boxes */
}

.d1>*>*>*:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.d1>*>*>*:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div>
    <div>
      <h4 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>                    
      <p  class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores!</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus, aperiam quasi voluptates assumenda neque fugiat. Enim ipsa quos facere, similique, iste placeat aperiam veniam, numquam qui neque illum odio!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h4 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>                    
      <p  class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores!</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus, aperiam quasi voluptates assumenda neque fugiat. Enim ipsa quos facere, similique, iste placeat aperiam veniam, numquam qui neque illum odio! Inventore necessitatibus, aperiam quasi voluptates assumenda neque fugiat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h4 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>                    
      <p  class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores!</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus, aperiam quasi voluptates assumenda neque fugiat. Enim ipsa quos facere, similique, iste placeat aperiam veniam, numquam qui neque illum odio!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h4 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>                    
      <p  class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores!</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus, aperiam quasi voluptates assumenda neque fugiat. Enim ipsa quos facere, similique, iste placeat aperiam veniam, numquam qui neque illum odio! Inventore necessitatibus, aperiam quasi voluptates assumenda neque fugiat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h4 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>                    
      <p  class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores!</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore necessitatibus, aperiam quasi voluptates assumenda neque fugiat. Enim ipsa quos facere, similique, iste placeat aperiam veniam, numquam qui neque illum odio!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I have retained a `<div>` to contain each slide for semantic reasons, but then in order for the grid to place the slide heading and slide contents into different cells, we need to tell CSS to ignore these slide `<div>`s by applying the rule `display: contents` to them.